# Anaconda Individual Edition 2020.11 will not install Geopandas

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, geopandas

I am a beginner in using anaconda and I need to install Geopandas for a task.
And when i ran the code conda install geopandas, it takes a long time and then returns the error message that has all of these conflicts (see attached).
And i have tried pip install geopandas, as well as pip install the different dependencies such as pandas, numpy, fiona, shapely, both in CMD and in the anaconda prompt and anaconda powershell. To my surprise, everything installed in the cmd but when I tried to import it in Anaconda, then it says no module named "Geopandas" found.

I have also tried conda install "conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas" and it still gives me the same issue.

I was wondering if anyone can help me solve this problem. I am working on a Windows 10 Laptop, with python 3.9 installed.

PS I am able to install everything in Anaconda Prompt but when I am trying to import t in anaconda, it deos not work.

Thanks so much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today installing geopandas in miniconda 3.9. Since miniconda is just a lightweigt version of anaconda, the solution might work there as well. I solved it:

1. Install miniconda 3.8
2. conda install geopandas (as the very first package). This downgrades python from 3.8.5 to 3.8.2
3. conda install ipykernel (or jupyter)